# SQL Pivot query with condition

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to convert rows to columns using `SQL` `Pivot`.

Here is my `table` structure

```
=====================
ID  CODE    CODE_TYPE        
=====================
1   C1          D
1   C2          D
1   C3          D
1   C4          D
1   C5          D
1   C6          D
1   C7          D
1   C8          D
1   C9          D
1   C10         D
1   C11         P
1   C12         P
1   C13         P   
1   C14         P   
1   C15         P   
1   C16         P
1   C17         P
1   C18         P
1   C19         P
1   C20         P
```

I want to convert `CODE` values to columns in the below format based on the `CODE_TYPE`

```
==================================================================================================================================================================
ID  CODE1   CODE2   CODE3   CODE4   CODE5   CODE6   CODE7   CODE8   CODE9   CODE10  CODE11  CODE12  CODE13  CODE14  CODE15  CODE16  CODE17  CODE18  CODE19  CODE20
==================================================================================================================================================================   
1   C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6      C7      C8      C9      C10     C11     C12     C13     C14     C15     C16     C17     C18     C19     C20
```

I have the below `SQL` `query`

```
SELECT  PIV.ID,
        PIV.[CODE1],
        PIV.[CODE2],
        PIV.[CODE3],
        PIV.[CODE4],
        PIV.[CODE5],
        PIV.[CODE6],
        PIV.[CODE7],
        PIV.[CODE8],
        PIV.[CODE9],
        PIV.[CODE10]
FROM (

            SELECT          
                    C.ID,
                    C.CODE,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ID  ORDER BY C.ID) AS 'CODE_NO' 
            FROM    CODE_TABLE C 
            WHERE C.CODE_TYPE='D'
        ) T1
PIVOT   (
            MAX(T1.CODE) 
            FOR T1.CODE_NO IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
        ) PIV
```

I am stuck with filtering `CODE_TYPE='P'`. 
All the `CODE_TYPE='P'` should be filled from `[11]-[20]`

Can someone help me out with this?

Thank you

Comment: Search for dynamic pivoting.

Comment: Do you always have 10 for each CODE_TYPE?

Comment: @Thomas I did look for dynamic pivot but I don't quite understand how can I filter records based on my CODE_TYPE.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes there can be 10 or less per CODE_TYPE!

Comment: The other thing that is unclear is how you define the order of the original rows. You have Order by ID but that is ambiguous.

Comment: @SeanLange I have another column File_ID which is used in the Order By too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation for this.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , CODE varchar(10)
    , CODE_TYPE char(1)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'C1', 'D')
, (1, 'C2', 'D')
, (1, 'C3', 'D')
, (1, 'C4', 'D')
, (1, 'C5', 'D')
, (1, 'C6', 'D')
, (1, 'C7', 'D')
, (1, 'C8', 'D')
, (1, 'C9', 'D')
, (1, 'C10', 'D')
, (1, 'C11', 'P')
, (1, 'C12', 'P')
, (1, 'C13', 'P')   
, (1, 'C14', 'P')   
, (1, 'C15', 'P')   
, (1, 'C16', 'P')
, (1, 'C17', 'P')
, (1, 'C18', 'P')
, (1, 'C19', 'P')
, (1, 'C20', 'P')
;
with SortedValues as
(
    select RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by CODE_TYPE, CODE)
        , *
    from @Something
)

select ID
    , max(case when RowNum = 1 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D'  then CODE end) as CODE1
, max (case when RowNum = 2 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE2
, max(case when RowNum = 3 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE3
, max(case when RowNum = 4 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE4
, max(case when RowNum = 5 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE5
, max(case when RowNum = 6 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE6
, max(case when RowNum = 7 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE7
, max(case when RowNum = 8 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE8
, max(case when RowNum = 9 AND CODE_TYPE = 'D' then CODE end) as CODE9
, max(case when RowNum = 10 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE10
, max(case when RowNum = 11 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE11
, max(case when RowNum = 12 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE12
, max(case when RowNum = 13 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE13
, max(case when RowNum = 14 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE14
, max(case when RowNum = 15 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE15
, max(case when RowNum = 16 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE16
, max(case when RowNum = 17 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE17
, max(case when RowNum = 18 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE18
, max(case when RowNum = 19 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE19
, max(case when RowNum = 20 AND CODE_TYPE = 'P' then CODE end) as CODE20
from SortedValues
group by ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this out! Much appreciated.

Comment: It is not filtering based on the Code_Type, I want Code1 ,Code2,...Code 10 to have Code_Type='D' and Code11, Code12,...Code20 to have Code_Type='P'.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean but I added a second predicate to the case expression....maybe that is what you mean?

Comment: The update helped, tweaked it a bit to fit my needs.Accepted it as the right answer.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dynamic pivot example.

```
DECLARE @code_type char(1) = 'P'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = '

SELECT  PIV.ID, ' + 
(
    SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('CODE' + REPLACE(CODE, 'C', '')) 
        FROM CodeTable 
        WHERE CODE_TYPE = @code_type 
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
) + '
FROM (    
        SELECT          
            C.ID,
            C.CODE,
            ''CODE'' + REPLACE(CODE, ''C'', '''') AS ''CODE_NO'' 
            FROM    CodeTable C 
            WHERE C.CODE_TYPE= ''' + @code_type + '''
        ) T1
PIVOT   (
            MAX(T1.CODE) 
            FOR T1.CODE_NO IN (' + 
            (
                SELECT STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('CODE' + REPLACE(CODE, 'C', '')) 
                    FROM CodeTable 
                    WHERE CODE_TYPE = @code_type 
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')
                ) + ')
        ) PIV'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Returns:

```
ID  CODE11  CODE12  CODE13  CODE14  CODE15  CODE16  CODE17  CODE18  CODE19  CODE20
1   C11     C12     C13     C14     C15     C16     C17     C18     C19     C20
```